# GDAL Python API - statistics valid percent information

Tags: python, gdal, gdal-python-binding

I would like to know if the STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT (percentage of valid (not nodata) pixels) information is accessible through the GDAL Python API?

It seems to be missing from the [GetStatistics Function](https://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a6aa58b6f0a0c17722b9bf763a96ff069).

As a work around, I have been scraping this information from the PAMDataset (XML file) generated through the GetStatistics(False, True) call.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2):

"Better" is subjective, so I won't claim that this is. But I much prefer using `rasterio` to "raw" GDAL or its python bindings. So if I wanted to know the fraction of cells with valid values, I would do the following:

#### Rasterio Approach

```
import rasterio
with rasterio.open('path/to/my/image.tif', 'r') as src:
    meta = src.meta.copy()
    data = src.read(1)

pct_valid = 100 * (data != meta['nodata']).sum() / (meta['width'] * meta['height'])
```

#### "Raw" GDAL

Alternatively, here's how you'd do it with GDAL's python bindings directly:

```
import gdal
gtif = gdal.Open('path/to/my/image.tif')
data = gtif.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
nd_val = band.GetNoDataValue()

pct_valid = 100 * (data != nd_val).sum() / (band.XSize * band.YSize)
gtif = None
```

#### Also consider

The `raster_stats` package may be even more concise, but I think it would required to you generate a vector layer encompassing the whole raster.

#### Links:

1. rasterio: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
2. raster_stats:
   https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the response. I agree that rasterio is generally easier to use and provides several advantages over the straight GDAL API. I would however prefer to stay within the confines of GDAL for my particular use case.

Comment: hey @BrentEdwards added a GDAL-based approach

Comment: Thanks Paul H! This should work in cases where the raster is small enough to be read directly into an array and thus avoiding the pain of windowing in GDAL.

Comment: band needs to be defined:
band = gtif.GetRasterBand(1)